# Is there more overhead to code in a single statement then to break it down step by step?

Tags: vb.net, performance, visual-studio-2012, coding-style

I'm relatively new to VB.NET and am self taught in programming so I am without a lot of foundation knowledge and concepts so please excuse my naivety and ignorance.

I am curious about the logistics, performance, and efficiency of writing VB functions step by step or just in one long line of code.

The following is a small function from one of my programs to parse some HTML. Please note that code is just a random example and both blocks of code perform exactly the same functions. They are here to illustrate my point of long, procedural declared, segmented etc. code in contrast with one long concise piece of code, respectively.

1. Long code

   ```
   Dim html As String
   Dim htmlString As String
   Dim dIndex As Integer
   html = WebBrowser.DocumentText
   htmlString = "size=" & Chr(34) & "15" & Chr(34) & " maxlength=" & Chr(34) & "40" & Chr(34) & ">"
   dIndex = html.IndexOf(htmlString)
   If (dIndex > -1) Then
       Dim lIndex As Integer
       Dim sDomain As String
       sDomain = html.Substring(dIndex + 26, 20)
       lIndex = sDomain.IndexOf("<")
       LblSubDomain.Text = sDomain.Substring(0, lIndex)
   Else
       LblSubDomain.Text = "Cannot Find Sub Domain Extension"
   End If
   ```
2. Short code

   ```
   If (WebBrowser.DocumentText.IndexOf("size=" & Chr(34) & "15" & Chr(34) & " maxlength=" & Chr(34) & "40" & Chr(34) & ">") > -1) Then
       LblSubDomain.Text = WebBrowser.DocumentText.Substring(WebBrowser.DocumentText.IndexOf("size=" & Chr(34) & "15" & Chr(34) & " maxlength=" & Chr(34) & "40" & Chr(34) & ">") + 26, 20).Substring(0, WebBrowser.DocumentText.Substring(WebBrowser.DocumentText.IndexOf("size=" & Chr(34) & "15" & Chr(34) & " maxlength=" & Chr(34) & "40" & Chr(34) & ">") + 26, 20).IndexOf("<"))
   Else
       LblSubDomain.Text = "Cannot Find Sub Domain Extension"
   End If
   ```

My question is: 
Which of the two blocks of code will have the least impact on performance or does VB2012 compile it to one line of code so that it makes no difference?

Thank you guys so much and I hope my question falls within the scope of expectations of Stack Overflow

Comment: I don't know whether your second version compiles to more efficient code or not, but if I had to maintain it I'd curse all the way to hell and back. Any minor performance penalty in the first version is outweighed by its readability.

Comment: I understand. Personally for me once I've finished with a function I like to ship it out of my sight so I can focus on something else. The smaller it looks to me the easier to traverse the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will effectively produce the same code, performance-wise.

From a maintainability and debugging standpoint, option #1 is much preferred as it allows for easier injection of break points via Visual Studio and it is generally easier to understand as the amount of logic in each line is smaller.

I would actually advocate a happy-medium between the two options, call it Option #1.5:

```
Dim html As String = WebBrowser.DocumentText
Dim htmlString As String = "size=" & Chr(34) & "15" & Chr(34) & " maxlength=" & Chr(34) & "40" & Chr(34) & ">"
Dim dIndex As Integer = html.IndexOf(htmlString)

If (dIndex > -1) Then
    Dim lIndex As Integer = sDomain.IndexOf("<")
    Dim sDomain As String = html.Substring(dIndex + 26, 20)

    LblSubDomain.Text = sDomain.Substring(0, lIndex)
Else
    LblSubDomain.Text = "Cannot Find Sub Domain Extension"
End If
```

This allows for less total lines of code, but keeps much of the readability, maintainability and debuggability that option #1 provided.

Here is the code decompiled into Intermediate Language (IL) via Reflector:

Note: `MySub()` is Option #1 decompiled into IL.

```
.method public instance void MySub() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 num,
        [1] string str,
        [2] string str2,
        [3] int32 num2,
        [4] string str3,
        [5] bool flag)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: callvirt instance class    [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_WebBrowser()
    L_0007: callvirt instance string [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser::get_DocumentText()
    L_000c: stloc.1 
    L_000d: ldstr "size=\"15\" maxlength=\"40\">"
    L_0012: stloc.2 
    L_0013: ldloc.1 
    L_0014: ldloc.2 
    L_0015: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::IndexOf(string)
    L_001a: stloc.0 
    L_001b: ldloc.0 
    L_001c: ldc.i4.m1 
    L_001d: cgt 
    L_001f: stloc.s flag
    L_0021: ldloc.s flag
    L_0023: brfalse.s L_0057
    L_0025: ldloc.1 
    L_0026: ldloc.0 
    L_0027: ldc.i4.s 0x1a
    L_0029: add.ovf 
    L_002a: ldc.i4.s 20
    L_002c: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.String::Substring(int32, int32)
    L_0031: stloc.s str3
    L_0033: ldloc.s str3
    L_0035: ldstr "<"
    L_003a: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::IndexOf(string)
    L_003f: stloc.3 
    L_0040: ldarg.0 
    L_0041: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_LblSubDomain()
    L_0046: ldloc.s str3
    L_0048: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0049: ldloc.3 
    L_004a: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.String::Substring(int32, int32)
    L_004f: callvirt instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label::set_Text(string)
    L_0054: nop 
    L_0055: br.s L_0069
    L_0057: nop 
    L_0058: ldarg.0 
    L_0059: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_LblSubDomain()
    L_005e: ldstr "Cannot Find Sub Domain Extension"
    L_0063: callvirt instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label::set_Text(string)
    L_0068: nop 
    L_0069: nop 
    L_006a: nop 
    L_006b: ret 
}
```

Note: `MySub2()` is Option #2 decompiled into IL.

```
.method public instance void MySub2() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 6
    .locals init (
        [0] bool flag)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_WebBrowser()
    L_0007: callvirt instance string [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser::get_DocumentText()
    L_000c: ldstr "size=\"15\" maxlength=\"40\">"
    L_0011: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::IndexOf(string)
    L_0016: ldc.i4.m1 
    L_0017: cgt 
    L_0019: stloc.0 
    L_001a: ldloc.0 
    L_001b: brfalse.s L_008f
    L_001d: ldarg.0 
    L_001e: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_LblSubDomain()
    L_0023: ldarg.0 
    L_0024: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_WebBrowser()
    L_0029: callvirt instance string [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser::get_DocumentText()
    L_002e: ldarg.0 
    L_002f: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_WebBrowser()
    L_0034: callvirt instance string [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser::get_DocumentText()
    L_0039: ldstr "size=\"15\" maxlength=\"40\">"
    L_003e: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::IndexOf(string)
    L_0043: ldc.i4.s 0x1a
    L_0045: add.ovf 
    L_0046: ldc.i4.s 20
    L_0048: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.String::Substring(int32, int32)
    L_004d: ldc.i4.0 
    L_004e: ldarg.0 
    L_004f: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_WebBrowser()
    L_0054: callvirt instance string [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser::get_DocumentText()
    L_0059: ldarg.0 
    L_005a: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_WebBrowser()
    L_005f: callvirt instance string [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser::get_DocumentText()
    L_0064: ldstr "size=\"15\" maxlength=\"40\">"
    L_0069: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::IndexOf(string)
    L_006e: ldc.i4.s 0x1a
    L_0070: add.ovf 
    L_0071: ldc.i4.s 20
    L_0073: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.String::Substring(int32, int32)
    L_0078: ldstr "<"
    L_007d: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::IndexOf(string)
    L_0082: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.String::Substring(int32, int32)
    L_0087: callvirt instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label::set_Text(string)
    L_008c: nop 
    L_008d: br.s L_00a1
    L_008f: nop 
    L_0090: ldarg.0 
    L_0091: callvirt instance class [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label WindowsApplication3.Form1::get_LblSubDomain()
    L_0096: ldstr "Cannot Find Sub Domain Extension"
    L_009b: callvirt instance void [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Label::set_Text(string)
    L_00a0: nop 
    L_00a1: nop 
    L_00a2: nop 
    L_00a3: ret 
}
```

Note: [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) is no longer a free product beyond a trial period, but there are free alternatives to get the IL for your code (`ildasm` is a tool built into the .NET Framework and [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) is the open-source response to Reflector no longer being free)

Comment: Thank you Karl.
Can you confirm that the performance is the same?
I left the question slightly open ended in the hope I would receive some common practice tips.
I appreciate your 1.5 medium. Are you able to help me understand the true necessity of debugging? My understanding is that if it works then it works. I have not yet learned the true purpose and practice of debugging. I have really just been code-styling for what I thought was performance and efficiency.

Comment: + @Iniquity666: Karl's right. Performance will not be affected in the slightest. Debugging is something you should get good at. When you write a program it is very unusual to write it with no mistakes. If you learn to set breakpoints and step through the code, line-by-line, examining data as you go, you can find the mistakes and fix them. Good luck!

Comment: @Iniquity666 - I have posted the decompiled code (IL) for each of the options and you can see it is essentially doing the same thing. Option #1 stores more items on the stack (`.locals init`), because of the `Dim`s that it is doing, while Option #2 makes a few more calls to get the values in the code itself.

Comment: @KarlAnderson - Thank you for your effort. Your research is very informing and I now see how little performance difference is truly made. This is precisely what I had hoped for plus more. On a side note I am curious as to why the use of break points could prove more effective at debugging code as opposed to just letting the Visual Studio throw errors at runtime?

Comment: @Iniquity666 - Debugging is the process of determining why a piece of logic does not work correctly, based upon the state of the system (read: data at a particular point in time). Letting the system throw errors at run-time is one way of being alerted to a problem with your code, but it does not allow for you to look at the inner workings of the code while it is running, because a thrown error is post-mortem. The Visual Studio debugger is quite powerful, in that it allows you to not only set breakpoints, but also to change the values of variables at run-time and also change the line executing.

Comment: @Iniquity666 - Watch [Visual Basic / Visual Studio Video Tutorial - Basic Debugging](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uk-a7qVa36c) and [How Do I: Learn Tips and Tricks for Debugging in Visual Studio?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uyDBM-qTkk), although the second one is using C# it will still be beneficial in showing you some of the more powerful features of the Visual Studio debugger.